# How to create a speech bubble in css?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I would like to create a speech like this,

[image]

I try to create using CSS. But I cannot align the top arrow like this. My Code is,

```css
.bubble
{
  position: relative;
  width: 275px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #C00006;
  -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
  -moz-border-radius: 14px;
  border-radius: 14px;
}

.bubble:after
{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 19px 79px;
  border-color: #C00006 transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: -19px;
  top: -79px;
  left: 69%;
}
```

```html
<br><br><br><br>
<div class="bubble"></div>
```

**[Online example](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodvt22/re61160t/1/)** *(on JSFiddle)*.

Comment: Apply a 3D Transform to it; perspective.

Comment: see this , may be this can be useful http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could achieve that by using [`skewX` transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) and specifying the [origin of the transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) as follows:

```css
.bubble {
    position: relative;
        top: 4.8em;
    width: 275px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #C00006;
    -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius: 14px;
    border-radius: 14px;
}

.bubble:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 19px 79px;
    border-color: #C00006 transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    /* top: -79px; */
    bottom: 100%; /* better than specifying the top */
    right: 38px;  /* equal to width of the arrow, for instance */
    
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: skewX(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(-45deg);
    -o-transform: skewX(-45deg);
    transform: skewX(-45deg);
    
    -webkit-transform-origin: 38px 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 38px 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 38px 100%;
    -o-transform-origin: 38px 100%;
    transform-origin: 38px 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble"></div>
```

It's worth noting that CSS transforms [are supported in IE 9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) and newer.

Comment: @diEcho I didn't refined the other declarations completely, just for the sake of completeness, there's no need you use vendor prefixes of `border-radius` anymore, and also `display: block` on the pseudo-element is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CSS3 [skew()](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) method on your `:after` psuedo selector like this:

```
.bubble:after {
    -ms-transform: skew(-40deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-40deg, 0deg);
    transform: skew(-40deg, 0deg);
}
```

Here's a **[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/re61160t/2/)**.

```css
.bubble {
  position: relative;
  width: 275px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #C00006;
  -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
  -moz-border-radius: 14px;
  border-radius: 14px;
}
.bubble:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 27px 79px;
  border-color: #C00006 transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: -19px;
  top: -79px;
  left: 69%;
  -ms-transform: skew(-40deg, 0deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-40deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(-40deg, 0deg);
}
```

```html
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="bubble"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/harshdand/gczu8w4e/

```
.bubble:after
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 19px 120px;
    border-color: #C00006 transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: -49px;
    top: -79px;
    left: 95%;
    -ms-transform: (50deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(50deg);
    transform: rotate(50deg);
}
```

transform: rotate(50deg);

#### edit

usw `skew` instead of `rotate` . see the snippet with minimal CSS

**`transform: skew(-45deg);`**

```css
.bubble {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -70px;
  width: 275px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #C00006;
  border-radius: 14px;
}
.bubble:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 19px 79px;
  border-color: #C00006 transparent;
  width: 1px;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 95%;
  left: 79%;
  transform: skew(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble"></div>
```

Comment: this will lift up from baseline